# How to insert matrix which had null elements in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I want to insert a `matrix` which had null elements in Matlab, How can I do that?
for example consider this `matrix`:

```
R=[1,null,3,4,5 | 6,7,null,8,null | null,null, 9,10,11]
```

Note that:

1. I separate columns by "|".
2. R is kind of Sparse Matrix.
3. These null values can't be zero or any special number.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried NAN ? You may like to see the link http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/14663